# PL SQL procedure not raising exception no_data_found

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables as `customers` and `orders` as follows:
Customers:

```sql
+----+------+------------+
| ID | Name | Contact_no |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 | Matt | 9435112340 |
|  2 | John | 6654342312 |
|  3 | Jill | 6654342312 |
+----+------+------------+
```

Orders:

```sql
+----------+------------+----------+------+
| Order_id | Order_date | Quantity | C_id |
+----------+------------+----------+------+
|     1011 | 09-jan-18  |       30 |    1 |
|     1012 | 09-feb-18  |      300 |    1 |
|     1013 | 09-feb-18  |      200 |    3 |
|     1111 | 09-feb-18  |      100 |    1 |
|     1016 | 09-feb-18  |       20 |    2 |
+----------+------------+----------+------+
```

I am writing a `PL/SQL` procedure which lists the `id`, `name` and `contact_no` of those who have the order quantity greater than 200. I am able to achieve this. But if no records exists, then i want to print a message "No Records Found". I know that if there are no records, then `oracle` throws `no_data_found` exception. Thus, I have written my procedure according to that. But, though there are not records, `oracle` is not throwing exception and my `Exception` block is not executing and nothing is printing as output. Can anyone please help what is going wrong and how can i achieve the required results? Below is my procedure.

```sql
DECLARE
    CURSOR cust_cur IS
    SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customers.id IN (SELECT c_id FROM orders WHERE orders.quantity>300 group by c_id);
BEGIN
    FOR cust IN cust_cur LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('Customer_id Customer_Name Customer_Phone');
        dbms_output.put_line(cust.id||' '||cust.name||' '||cust.contact_no);
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('No data found');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error Due To -->'|| SQLCODE||SQLERRM);
END;
```

I have changed the condition of quantity in SQL statement from 200 to 300, as it will return no rows.

Answer (score 1):

no_data_dound is raised only by select..into..from clause
This "FOR cust IN cust_cur LOOP" is a loop and not a select statement.. loops like these are treated as bulk collect statements by oracle internally and default limit to which is 100.

Comment: so, how can i achieve the result i want? what changes i need to do in the `procedure`?

Comment: go with cust_cur%rowcount. raise exception if this comes up zero.

Comment: I have just tried with `%rowcount`, but still it is not working

Comment: Could you share reference to oracle documentation on your statement- "oops like these are treated as bulk collect statements by oracle internally and default limit to which is 100". I don't think that is a correct statement.

Comment: @VN'sCorner : i don't exactly remember where i gained this knowledge from.. It's been too long working on Oracle database. Still, I found this page which tells about oracle's implicit limit to for cursor loops :- http://www.dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_limit_clause.htm

Answer (score 1):

You may control data count in loop manually.
Like below.

```sql
declare
   cursor cust_cur
   is
      select *
        from customers
       where customers.id in (  select c_id
                                  from orders
                                 where orders.quantity > 300
                              group by c_id);

   l_count   number := 0;
begin
   for cust in cust_cur
   loop
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Customer_id Customer_Name Customer_Phone');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         cust.id || ' ' || cust.name || ' ' || cust.contact_no);
      l_count := 1;
   end loop;

   if l_count = 0
   then
      raise NO_DATA_FOUND;
   end if;
exception
   when NO_DATA_FOUND
   then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('No data found');
   when others
   then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error Due To -->' || SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
end;
```

Comment: Mustafa's got the right idea! I would use a boolean l_rows_round instead of an integer. I would also NOT raise the exception, just IF NOT l_rows_found THEN (print desired information). But the bottom line is that you want to take advantage of the convenience (and automatic optimization) of a cursor for loop, then you have to do a little extra work to detect the behavior of the cursor once it's closed implicitly by the PL/SQL runtime engine.

Comment: Thank you Steven. Boolean sounds better.And the reason i'm using "raise"  to show how we go to "exception".Can you explain the part with begin "bottom line " more simply? Thank you again.

Comment: When you use a cursor for loop, Oracle does lots of the work for you (declaring a record implicitly, open, fetch, close). Plus automatically optimizes to return 100 rows with each fetch. But this also means that after the cursor is closed, you don't have any information (via % cursor attributes) to what happened INSIDE the loop. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, very clear.Thank you for detailed explanation.